# sequences for writing embedded drivers

Tags: c, embedded, system

I'm really confused when I'm writing a driver? just need to know which file should I write first header file, or the configuration file otherwise the code file. just for example keypad driver using C. if there any resources to understand more these steps for writing driver I will be very thankful

Comment: Why would you write one file at a time in a sequence at all?  Who codes anything in that way? Design-implement-test is the sequence, and even then it is normally iterative - there is no sequence of file construction, nor any need for such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be it a driver development or application development,
Very first step is be clear with requirement,
Then have a proper design and then go for coding.

Note that coding without design is a disaster.

Which file to start with is your question?

If you are so much confused just start with code file.

Keep entire code in that file.

Later on you can re arrange your code to different files like header file , Config file , code file etc...